# How can i improve the performance of drawing an animation path?

Tags: javascript, animation, kineticjs

I drew a rectangle with kinetic.js and animating it in a circular path. In each animation frame i reduce it's radius, and i draw animating path of this object by kineticJS Line. But This Kinetics animation loop develops an undesirable pausing "stagger". This stagger is small in Chrome, noticeable in IE and horrible in FireFox. This seems to be due to the Kinetic.Line being unable to smoothly add + draw thousands of changing points of data. How can make this animation flawless, smooth. It would be great help if you give me the link of a jsfiddle. Bunches of thanks in advance.

**CODES:**

```
var R= 80;

$(document).ready(function(){
var stage= new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width:500,
    height:500
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var line = new Kinetic.Line({
    points:[0,0,0,0],
    stroke:'blue',
    strokeWidth:2
});
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x:10,
    y:10,
    width:10,
    height: 10,
    fill:'black',
    stroke:'red'
});
layer.add(rect);
layer.add(line);
stage.add(layer);

var centerX = stage.width()/2;
var points=[];
var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(
        function(f){
            var cX= stage.width()/2;
            var cY= stage.height()/2;
            R=R-1/100;
            var X = cX + R*Math.cos(f.time/1000);
            var Y = cY+ R*Math.sin(f.time/1000);
            points.push(X,Y);
            line.setPoints(points);
            rect.setX(X);
            rect.setY(Y);
        }
,layer);
anim.start();
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/tanvirgeek/n8z8N/7/

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you’ve discovered, updating and drawing a Kinetic.Line containing thousands of line segments causes a noticable lag.

One Kinetic trick that I rarely seen used is useful to create a lag-free animation of thousands of line segments.

First, draw your line segments on an off-screen html5 canvas.  When a new line segment is needed, just add that segment to all the pre-existing segments.  This is very efficient because only the last line segment needs to be drawn.

You can use a Kinetic.Image to display the offscreen html5 canvas on the screen.

The trick is to set the Kinetic.Image image-source to the html canvas: `myKineticImage.setImage(myOffscreenCanvas)`.  This works because “behind the scenes” the Kinetic.Image is using `context.drawImage` to display its image.  Since context.drawImage can also accept another canvas as its image-source, you can efficiently display the current offscreen canvas drawings.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/rYC96/

[image]

And example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    // variables used to set the stage and animate
    var rectSize=15;
    var cx=stage.getWidth()/2;
    var cy=stage.getHeight()/2;
    var R=100;
    var A=0;
    var deltaA=Math.PI/180;
    var lastX=cx+R*Math.cos(A);
    var lastY=cy+R*Math.sin(A);

    // the html canvas incrementally draws the line segments
    // which are in turn displayed as a Kinetic.Image (called line)
    var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width=stage.getWidth();
    canvas.height=stage.getHeight();
    ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
    ctx.lineWidth=2;


    // this Kinetic.Image exactly displays the current html canvas drawings
    // (this trick cures the lags)
    var line=new Kinetic.Image({
        x:0,
        y:0,
        width:canvas.width,
        height:canvas.height,
        image:canvas
    });
    layer.add(line);


    // the rotating Kinetic.Rectangle
    var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x:lastX,
        y:lastY,
        width:rectSize,
        height:rectSize,
        fill:'black',
        stroke:'red'
    });
    layer.add(rect);


    // use requestAnimationFrame (RAF) to drive the animation
    // RAF efficiently schedules animation frames with display 
    function animate(){

        // stop animating when rect reaches center
        if(R<=rectSize/2){return;}

        // schedule another animation frame even before this one is done
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        // calc the new XY position
        R=R-.01;
        A+=deltaA;
        var X=cx+R*Math.cos(A);
        var Y=cy+R*Math.sin(A);

        // animate the rect and line to their next position

        // draw just the latest line segment to the canvas
        // (all the previous line segments are still there--no need to redraw them)
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(X,Y);
        ctx.stroke();
        // set lastXY for next frame
        lastX=X;
        lastY=Y;

        // update the rect position
        rect.setX(X);
        rect.setY(Y);

        // draw the changed line-image and rect to the kinetic layer
        layer.draw();
    }

    // start animating!
    animate();

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You the man!! Guru, It would be great if i can follow you on twitter. Thanks again.